# Possible to Geo-tag Photos using iPhone ImagePicker?

Tags: iphone, geotagging

When calling the ImagePicker to take a picture the user is not prompted to allow their location to be used to geo-tag the photo as with the native Camera app.  Is it possible to turn on or build geo-tagging into the ImagePicker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could simply get the photo via the ImagePicker, then prompt the user to approve getting their location (something you have to do anyway) and then store both image and location in your own object.

I don't believe the Picker by itself embeds lat/long in the image. That's likely something happening elsewhere in the Camera app.

You could check using this lib though:

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/downloads/list

Good Luck!